# SQL Server: Query Right Join

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables:

**Users:**

```
Oid | email | pass
```

**Dist:**

```
Oid | Name | Users
```

**CS:**

```
Oid | Name | Users | Dist
```

I want to bring all Of the users and also the name of the CS and the name of the Dist, if is the case.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
    Users.*, CS.OID as OidCS, CS.Name as NameCs,
    Dist.OID as OidDist, Dist.Name as NameDist
FROM
    Dist, Users
RIGHT JOIN 
    CS on CS.Users = Users.OID
WHERE 
    CS.Dist = Dist.OID
```

But this query doesn't bring me the Dist Users and I need them both (Cs and Dist), I don't know how to approach for the solution, How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: HINT: `from users ... left join dist .... left join cs...`

Comment: Please don't mix implicit and explicit join syntax.  It causes extremely weird issues.  You should *never* have a comma in the `FROM` clause, as a rule-of-thumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing an ancient implicit `JOIN` syntax (that has been deprecated for [**over 25 years**](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)) with an explicit one.  This is going to cause some issues with your results.

As a rule-of-thumb, you should *never* have a `,` in the `FROM` clause.  You should *always* use explicit the `JOIN` syntax.

In this case, using a `LEFT JOIN` makes more logical sense.  You're wanting to select everything from `Users` and select records from `Dist` and `CS` if they exist.

This should get you what you need:

```
Select      U.*, C.OID As OIDCS, C.Name As NameCs,
            D.OID As OIDDist, D.Name As NameDist
From        Users   U
Left Join   CS      C   On  U.OID = C.Users
Left Join   Dist    D   On  D.OID = C.Dist
```

Comment: I'd think it would be on `D.User = U.OID` based this logic or all on the OID. Granted it's hard to tell from the OP.  But i think this would throw an error that the c.Dist could not be bound, no? Meaning we'd need to change the order of the joins.

Answer (score -1):

may be there is a problem in your sql syntax you are using table names as for matches like this.

WHERE CS.Dist=Dist.OID.

**CS** is a  **table** and **Dist** is also a table you are using assignment operator here you have to update the logic here compare columns of table not two tables.

got it?

Comment: the can you please share how can we write just one left join in a query?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but I have `Left Join`s in my answer if that's what you're looking for..

Comment: @MuhammadAmirShahzad You can implicitly join tables by using a `FROM tblA, tblB WHERE tblA.Id = tblB.Id`  but it's not the standard way to do it.

Comment: @EMUEVIL It hasn't been the standard for [over 25 years](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).  And some newer versions of DBMS's don't even fully support them anymore.  It's better to not use them at all.

Comment: @Siyual I wholeheartedly agree with you. But it seems like Muhammad Amir SHahzad was saying that comparing values from different tables in a `WHERE` clause won't work.